# What resister I want to use to drop voltage for LED?

Tags: led, resistors, transformerless

I am going to connect 10 led in series without a transformer.

Now I want to know the value of resister to connect 10 led in series

and please give the calculation method

thank you.

Comment: You need to know the forward voltage drop of your LEDs for this calculation, as well as what voltage you will supply.

Comment: Are you powering this with mains? If so there is probably a much safer way to achieve what you want. What are your LEDs?

Comment: Sorry i did not mention that.
I am going to use main power 220v
and 3.3v blue led 20mA

Comment: please explain about it

Comment: Use a power supply. You can get 5 V supplies for charging phones for next to nothing. They shouldn't kill you.

Comment: Calculation method: V=IR.

Comment: @Puffafish  can you please show the resister value for above values

Answer (score 0):

> I am going to use main power 220v and 3.3v blue led 20mA

**DON'T!!!!!!! Do NOT use mains power!**

So the answer to your question is *YOU CAN'T*, at least not safely.